# Upload file with PHP easy way

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, upload

I have tried this tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

And no success :(

I do not understand the point where this guy states

> The following example below attempts to copy a file uploaded by the HTML Form listed in previous section page to /var/www/html directory which is document root of your PHP server

I tried using the filesystem path to the php script : `I:\xampp\htdocs\tester\` (normally the .php is here) and it wouldn't work.

I get this error :

> Warning: copy(stock-footage-hand-presses-a-confidential-stamp-contains-matte.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in I:\xampp\htdocs\tester\uploader.php on line 4
>
> Could not copy file!

I do not understand what i am doing wrong, and if you could give me a little example, i would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough, you're trying to write to something that doesn't exist, so are you sure the folder is really where you think it is, and that there are no typos.

Comment: we can't tell what you are doing wrong with out seeing your code. The only thing we can guess at is that you are not setting the path correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am not used to asking questions and everything, i don't really know where to start and what to show up here. Adeneo : Yes, the folderr exists under that path. I don't know why it's not dropping the file where entended, because i even tried this whole tutorial using the preset values on his page (changed nothing at all except the file path) and no good :/ I'm totally lost with PHP, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["uploadnow"]))
{
    $directory  = "images/";    //directory name where the image should get stored
    $imageDet   = $_FILES["uploadfile"];
    if($imageDet["name"]!="")
    {
        //source as tmpname and destination as destination directory
        copy($imageDet["tmp_name"],$directory.$imageDet["name"]);
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Now" name="uploadnow" />
</form>
```

Hope the above code would be helpful. and note that the directory (the destination directory) has to be present for uploading.
Note : `method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is must when you upload a file from form.

Comment: My friend this worked properly without flaws! It uploads anything i ask for! Is there a way i can access the filename by any chances using this method?? Because i would need to create a link to this file as well, therefore all i really need is its filename so i can drop it into a text file or an XML file. Or is it simply the ["name"] tag in there? Thanks again, really appreciated.